# Button to open a window in CRM2011: Could not load type

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I've created a simple ribbon button which opens a new ASPX page and passes some parameters to it.

I've placed the page along with it's .DLL files in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CRMWeb\ISV\<My Web Folder>`.

The ribbon button links to `/ISV/<My Web Folder>/<My page>.aspx`

But all I'm getting is a CRM error. If I look in the event viewer, I can see this:

```
Event code: 3006 
 Event message: A parser error has occurred. 
 Event time: 2011-04-21 11:23:26 
 Event time (UTC): 2011-04-21 09:23:26 
 Event ID: a2f50bca417344949bd8d0acde5e1c61 
 Event sequence: 1591 
 Event occurrence: 9 
 Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
 Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-3-129477829326577670 
 Trust level: Full 
 Application Virtual Path: / 
 Application Path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CRMWeb\ 
 Machine name: SRV-CRM-D03 

Process information: 
 Process ID: 1772 
 Process name: w3wp.exe 
 Account name: DEV\CRM 

Exception information: 
 Exception type: HttpParseException 
 Exception message: Could not load type <Type of my ASPX form>
 (...)
```

I'm guessing CRM isn't looking for the DLL where it should. What's the solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you place the assembly for the page? It should be in the `bin`folder of Dynamics CRM.

Please keep in mind that the ISV-Directory is officially deprecated and should not be used for new development. It is only there for backward compatibility. See how to  
[Upgrade Code in the ISV folder to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309571.aspx)

Another option is to use HTML pages and JavaScript which could be deployed with a solution and could use the new REST endpoints.

Comment: I actually got it working by changing the button link to /../ISV/<My application>... However, I do understand that the ISV is deprecated; we just wanted to get our app working with the new CRM for a presentation. Still, even this solution is not ideal, as some users get the "this organization is disabled" error for some reason.